# Screenshot Of webView with full image quality

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, pdf-generation

I am trying to take a screenshot of a webView and change it to PDF. I have used this method: http://www.ioslearner.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/HtmlToPdfDemo.zip

I mean the code in this project. It works fine for iPad but it doesn't covers full width for iPhone. I have used -sizeThatFits: for the webView, but that gives unreadable images for large html pages. I have searched a lot but all I could find out was in Android.. not iPhone. Please help me.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By changing the webView's frame before you render it, you will be able to capture the entire page.

```
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, webView.scrollView.contentSize.width, webView.scrollView.contentSize.height);
[webView setFrame:contentRect];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, contentRect, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[webView.layer renderInContext:context];
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.But Will it take a screenshot of the visible part of webView or the whole webView? as webView.bounds gives the visible bounds only.

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper changed the code to include the entire webView

Comment: Amazing.. that is exactly waht i wanted... really thanx for your help 
:)